# Strange Javadoc wrapping in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

Why I am getting this strange formatting of Javadoc in Intellij? The wrapping is completely off:

[image: Strange Javadoc formatting in Intellij]

This is my Intellij Javdoc Formatting rules

[image: Intellij Javdoc Formatting rules]

Comment: Disable the `Wrap at right margin` setting?

Comment: I want the word wrap.

Comment: Actually disabling `Wrap at right margin` was correct; then `Wrapping and Braces` -> `Hard wrap at` kicked in and it wraps correctly now. Care to put that as an answer? If so, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the **Wrap at right margin** option and use the `Wrapping and Braces` | **Hard wrap at**. The current behavior is a bit confusing and there is [an open issue for that](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189748#focus=streamItem-27-2808035.0-0).

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the answer that @CrazyCoder provided messes up with line continuation indents. Specifically, that javadoc lines that are wrapped with **Hard wrap at** are not indented properly, even if the `JavaDoc` | **Indent continuation lines** option is enabled.

To preserver the line continuation indents I followed the instructions provided on the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189748#focus=streamItem-27-2808035.0-0) (posted, again, by @CrazyCoder) and I have also enabled `Wrapping and Braces` | **Wrap if long** at any place I could find.